# Confusion matrix if predicted class label is list of list and true value is list

Tags: python

I want to make a confusion matrix for my predicted class labels. For each row, I have predicted top five class labels and I have assigned it to a list of list. In my actual dataset for each row there is one class label associated. It has multiclass labels. I have used decision tree classification. Can  you suggest how to make confusion matrix and get TP,TN,FP,FN.
Here X is input row of the entire dataset. y is the target class labels of the dataset. clas is a list containing distinct class labels.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

indices=[]
DTC= DecisionTreeClassifier()
DTC.fit(X,y)


y_pre=DTC.predict_proba(X)
for sublist in y_pre:
    index1=sorted(range(len(sublist)), key=lambda i: sublist[i], reverse=True)[:5]
    indices.append(index1)  

m=[]    
for j in indices:
    for k in j:
       m.append(clas[k])

ans=list(zip(*[iter(m)]*5))
mat=confusion_matrix(y, ans)
print(mat)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you predict the top 5 classes for each sample and have only a single ground truth label?

Comment: Can you show your code and an example of expected output?

Comment: Actually, I am predicting top 5 classes for each sample and I am having only a single ground truth label . I am predicting the top five classes using predict_proba(). Using predict_proba() I am taking out the top five index having maximum probability and using that index I am fetching associated class labels stored in a separate list which contain unique class labels as arranged in a sequence as in dataset.

Comment: I have added my code.